# Как запустить функцию в callback magnific popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific

На форме есть чекбокс, чек которого снимает disable с кнопки. Если форма вызывается по ajax (используется magnific popup), код не работает. Как можно его вызвать через callback? Пробовал так, не сработало.

```
$('.ajax-popup').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax',
        callbacks: {
            /*ajaxContentAdded: function() {
                var test = $('.ajax-popup').find('.js-check');

                test.on('click', function () {
                    $(this).parents('.js-check-parent').find('.js-button').prop('disabled', function(i, v) { return !v; });
                });
            }*/
            updateStatus: function(data) {
                if(data.status === 'ready') {
                    var test = $('.ajax-popup').find('.js-check');

                    test.on('click', function () {
                        $(this).parents('.js-check-parent').find('.js-button').prop('disabled', function(i, v) { return !v; });
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        ajax: {
            settings: {
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    ajax: true
                }
            }
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Список обратных вызовов:

```
  beforeOpen: function() {
    console.log('Start of popup initialization');
  },
  elementParse: function(item) {
    console.log('Parsing content. Item object that is being parsed:', item);
  },
  change: function() {
    console.log('Content changed ' + this.content);
  },
  resize: function() {
    console.log('Popup resized');
  },
  open: function() {
    console.log('Popup is opened');
  },
  beforeClose: function() {
    console.log('Popup close has been initiated');
  },
  close: function() {
    console.log('Popup removal initiated (after removalDelay timer finished)');
  },
  afterClose: function() {
    console.log('Popup is completely closed');
  },
  markupParse: function(template, values, item) {
  },
  updateStatus: function(data) {
    console.log('Status changed', data);
  },
  imageLoadComplete: function() {
    console.log('Image loaded');
  },
  parseAjax: function(mfpResponse) {
    console.log('Ajax content loaded:', mfpResponse);
  },
  ajaxContentAdded: function() {
    console.log(this.content);
  }
```

Документация [Magnific Popup Documentation - API](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api)

> Вы можете определить обратные вызовы в опциях обратных вызовов
>   `callbacks`. Кроме того, все события Magnific Popup отправляются с
>   использованием `triggerHandler` в целевом элементе (или для документа,
>   если элемент не существует).

Немного о функции обратного вызова `updateStatus`, используемой вами:

- `data` - это объект, который имеет два свойства `status` и `text`
- `data.status` - текущий тип состояния, может быть «`loading`», «`error`», «`ready`»,
- `data.text` - текст, который будет отображаться (например, «Loading...»)
- вы можете изменить эти свойства, чтобы динамически изменять текущий статус или его текст

Если в функцию обратного вызова вы попадаете, значит `callback` работает и ошибка кроется в коде идущем далее.

```
var test = $('.ajax-popup').find('.js-check');
```

Убедитесь, что переменная `test` имеет значение, а также, что полученное значение - это то, что вы ожидали. В противном случае внесите изменения в код, чтобы получить нужный элемент.

```
test.on('click', function () {
    $(this)
      .parents('.js-check-parent')
      .find('.js-button')
      .prop('disabled', 
          function(i, v) { 
             return !v; 
          });
});
```

Что-то мне подсказывает, что возможно нужно начать с простого, а именно:

```
.prop('disabled', 
   function(i, v) { 
      return !v; 
   });
```

В документации есть примечание [.prop( propertyName, function)](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function):

> Note: If nothing is returned in the setter function (ie. `function(index, prop ){}`), or if `undefined` is returned, the current value is
>   not changed. This is useful for selectively setting values only when
>   certain criteria are met.

Перевод:

> Если в сеттер функции (т.е. `function( index, prop ){})`) ничего не
>   возвращается, или если возвращается `undefined` - текущее значение не
>   изменяется. Это полезно для выборочной установки значений, только при
>   выполнении определенных критериев.

Попробуйте заменить на более простой код, типа `.prop('disabled', true);` или `.prop('disabled', false);` в зависимости от вашего кода. Опять же, возможно код работает, но получаются не те элементы. Проверьте, что в `$(this).parents('.js-check-parent').find('.js-button')` находится нужное значние.

Для проверки достаточно написать несколько `console.log(...)`, а также не помешает `debugger` - чтобы посмотреть, что происходит и какие значения в данный момент. С точки зрения кода - код вполне нормальный.

Answer (score 1):

Соответственно [документации плагина](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api) попробуйте так:

```
callbacks: {
    open: function() {
        // Will fire when this exact popup is opened
        // this - is Magnific Popup object
```

Comment: С open пробовал, результат тот же - выполняется, например, consoleLog, но по клику и т.д. ничего не происходит.